# What Armenian letter is it?

Tags: armenian

What Armenian letter is it ???
[image]

Comment: Looks like a ﬓ, doesn't it?

Comment: This might also be Georgian, in the Nuskhuri orthography, possibly a ligature of _mani_ and _nari_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a ligature M+N, it's even [included](https://symbl.cc/en/FB13/) in Unicode, ﬓ U+FB13, symbols U+FB14 – U+FB17 are four more Armenian ligatures.[image]